# ByRef argument type mismatch Error in VBA Arrays

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to create a code to find intersection points between a Rotated rectangle and some horizontal lines
at this line there's an error "ByRef argument type mismatch" when I try to run the code

```
aa(i) = IntersectComplex(XLine1(i), YLine1(i), XLine2(i), YLine2(i), Side1, True)
```

Especially at "XLine1(i)" which is highlighted after clicking ok on the error message box

Full Code

```
Dim Xc(1 To 4) As Double
Dim Yc(1 To 4) As Double
Dim Theta_D, Theta_R As Double
Dim Xc_R(1 To 4) As Double
Dim Yc_R(1 To 4) As Double
Dim Side1, Side2, Side3, Side4 As Range
Dim nfibers As Integer
Dim x1(1 To 4), x2(1 To 4), y1(1 To 4), y2(1 To 4) As Double


Dim tf() As Double
Dim Yf(), df() As Double
Dim XLine1(), XLine2(), YLine1(), YLine2() As Double
Dim aa(), bb(), cc(), dd() As Double
Dim Xint1(), Xint2(), Xint3(), Xint4() As Variant
Dim Yint1(), Yint2(), Yint3(), Yint4() As Double
Dim Px1(), Px2() As Double
Dim XCG(), YCG() As Double

nfibers = 30

ReDim tf(1 To nfibers) As Double
ReDim Yf(1 To nfibers + 1), df(1 To nfibers + 1) As Double
ReDim XLine1(1 To nfibers + 1), XLine2(1 To nfibers + 1), YLine1(1 To nfibers + 1), YLine2(1 To nfibers + 1) As Double
ReDim aa(1 To nfibers + 1), bb(1 To nfibers + 1), cc(1 To nfibers + 1), dd(1 To nfibers + 1) As Double
ReDim Xint1(1 To nfibers + 1), Xint2(1 To nfibers + 1), Xint3(1 To nfibers + 1), Xint4(1 To nfibers + 1) As Variant
ReDim Yint1(1 To nfibers + 1), Yint2(1 To nfibers + 1), Yint3(1 To nfibers + 1), Yint4(1 To nfibers + 1) As Double
ReDim Px1(1 To nfibers + 1), Px2(1 To nfibers + 1) As Double
ReDim XCG(1 To nfibers), YCG(1 To nfibers) As Double



b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
t = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value
Theta_D = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Value
Theta_R = Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(Theta_D)

Cos_T = Math.Cos(Theta_R)
Sin_T = Math.Sin(Theta_R)
Tan_T = Math.Tan(Theta_R)

Xc(1) = b / 2
Xc(2) = -b / 2
Xc(3) = -b / 2
Xc(4) = b / 2
Xc(5) = b / 2

Yc(1) = t / 2
Yc(2) = t / 2
Yc(3) = -t / 2
Yc(4) = -t / 2
Yc(5) = t / 2

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value = Xc(1)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G4").Value = Xc(2)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I3").Value = Xc(2)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I4").Value = Xc(3)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K3").Value = Xc(3)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4").Value = Xc(4)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M3").Value = Xc(4)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M4").Value = Xc(1)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H3").Value = Yc(1)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H4").Value = Yc(2)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J3").Value = Yc(2)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J4").Value = Yc(3)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L3").Value = Yc(3)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L4").Value = Yc(4)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N3").Value = Yc(4)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N4").Value = Yc(1)

Set Side1 = Range("G3:H4")
Set Side2 = Range("I3:J4")
Set Side3 = Range("K3:L4")
Set Side4 = Range("M3:N4")


For i = 1 To 4 Step 1
    Xc_R(i) = (Xc(i) * Cos_T) + (Yc(i) * Sin_T)
    Yc_R(i) = (-Xc(i) * Sin_T) + (Yc(i) * Cos_T)
Next i

Y1max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Yc_R, 1)
Y2max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Yc_R, 2)
Y3max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Yc_R, 3)
Y4max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Yc_R, 4)

hzone1 = Y1max - Y2max
hzone2 = Y2max - Y3max
hzone3 = Y3max - Y4max

d1max = Y1max - Y1max
d2max = Y1max - Y2max
d3max = Y1max - Y3max
d4max = Y1max - Y4max

'each zone has equal fibers but not equal fiber thicknesses
If Theta_D = 0 Or Theta_D = 90 Or Theta_D = 180 Or Theta_D = 270 Or Theta_D = 360 Then
    nfibers_Zone1 = 0
    tf_zone1 = 0
    nfibers_Zone2 = nfibers
    tf_zone2 = hzone2 / nfibers_Zone2
    nfibers_Zone3 = 0
    tf_zone3 = 0
Else
    nfibers_Zone1 = nfibers / 3
    tf_zone1 = hzone1 / nfibers_Zone1
    nfibers_Zone2 = nfibers / 3
    tf_zone2 = hzone2 / nfibers_Zone2
    nfibers_Zone3 = nfibers / 3
    tf_zone3 = hzone3 / nfibers_Zone3
End If

'Line Starts and ends
For i = 1 To 4
    x1(i) = Xc_R(i)
    x2(i) = Xc_R(i + 1)
    y1(i) = Yc_R(i)
    y2(i) = Yc_R(i + 1)
Next i

'Horizontal Lines for fibers
'Different zones
'Zone1
For i = 0 To nfibers
    If i >= 0 And i < nfibers / 3 Then
        tff = tf_zone1
    ElseIf i >= (nfibers / 3) And i < (2 / 3) * nfibers Then
        tff = tf_zone2
    Else
        tff = tf_zone3
    End If
    
    Yf(i) = Y1max - (tff * i)
    df(i) = Y1max - Yf(i)
    
    YLine1(i) = Yf(i)
    YLine2(i) = Yf(i)
    
    XLine1(i) = -100000
    XLine2(i) = 100000
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
    aa(i) = IntersectComplex(XLine1(i), YLine1(i), XLine2(i), YLine2(i), Side1, True)
    bb(i) = IntersectComplex(XLine1(i), YLine1(i), XLine2(i), YLine2(i), Side2, True)
    cc(i) = IntersectComplex(XLine1(i), YLine1(i), XLine2(i), YLine2(i), Side3, True)
    dd(i) = IntersectComplex(XLine1(i), YLine1(i), XLine2(i), YLine2(i), Side4, True)
    
    Xint1(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(aa(i), "")
    Xint2(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(bb(i), "")
    Xint3(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(cc(i), "")
    Xint4(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(dd(i), "")
    
    Yint1(i) = Yf(i)
    Yint2(i) = Yf(i)
    Yint3(i) = Yf(i)
    Yint4(i) = Yf(i)
    
    If Xint1(i) <> "" Then
        Px1(i) = Xint1(i)
    ElseIf Xint2(i) <> "" Then
        Px1(i) = Xint2(i)
    ElseIf Xint3(i) <> "" Then
        Px1(i) = Xint3(i)
    End If
    
    If Xint2(i) <> "" Then
        Px2(i) = Xint2(i)
    ElseIf Xint3(i) <> "" Then
        Px2(i) = Xint3(i)
    ElseIf Xint4(i) <> "" Then
        Px2(i) = Xint4(i)
    End If
    
    
Next i

For i = 1 To nfibers
    XCG(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Px1(i), Px2(i))
    YCG(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Yf(i), Yf(i))
Debug.Print XCG(i)
Debug.Print YCG(i)

Next i
```

Comment: By the way, I'm using Andy Pope's UDF "IntersectComplex" to find the coordinates of intersection between two lines  https://andypope.info/charts/intersection.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you declared several variables separated by commas `Dim XLine1(), XLine2(), YLine1(), YLine2() As Double`, without specifying the type of each of them, but only the last one. Thus, all variables except the last one are of type Variant by default. See [Dim statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement): "Use a separate As type clause for each variable you declare.".
Passing a variable of type Variant instead of Double to the `Public Function IntersectComplex(x1 As Double, y1 As Double, x2 As Double, y2 As Double, LineCoordinates As Range, Axis As Boolean) As Variant` by reference causes a type error.
See the example below:

```
Sub testWrong()
    Dim arr(), arr2() As Double 'arr() was declared as Variant by default, arr2() was explicitly declared as Double
    ReDim arr(1 To 2), arr2(1 To 2) As Double
    arr(1) = 100
    arr2(1) = 200
    foo arr(1), arr2(1) ' passed arr(1) ByRef as Variant. Raise error "ByRef argument type mismatch": expected Double, passed Variant
End Sub

Sub foo(x As Double, x2 As Double)
    Debug.Print x * x2
End Sub

Sub testRight()
    Dim arr() As Double, arr2() As Double 'you need to explicitly specify the type after each variable
    ReDim arr(1 To 2), arr2(1 To 2) ' no need to specify type here
    arr(1) = 100
    arr2(1) = 200
    foo arr(1), arr2(1) 'no error
End Sub
```